# Bash output all links in following format

Tags: linux, bash

i want to display all links in a directory in the following format:

```
linkname -> path/of/the/link
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find to search for symbolic links and use the builtin function printf to make it look like you want:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f -> %l\n"
```

Explanation: **find .** searches in the actual directory, **-maxdepth 1** only looks this directory, if omitting find runs through all subdirectories, **-type l** looks only for symbolic links, **%f** means the filename and **%l** the target of the link (empty if no link)

Answer (score 0):

As only links contain the characters `->`:

```
ls -ltra | grep "\-\>" or:
ls -ltra | grep "\->" (not tested)
```